# How to find product guid in xml file using select-string?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

We are having a xml file where in few attributes we stored product guid.

I am trying to find the guid using powershell select-string cmdlet but it returns no value.

```
GEt-content rules.xml | Select-String "5351BABA-40C2-477B-8111-DA54A48CD8EB"
```

The guid is there in the file and i verified manually.

Why select-string unable to find product guid? is there any alternative to find whether it is available or not?

Sample content from xml file

```
<Component Id="M_PostConfig" Name="Post-Configuration" StsDisplayEntry="Database Server Post-Configuration" StsDisplayText="Please wait while Post-Configuration is installed" UninstallCommand="&quot;%pTxtFoldrSystem32%\msiexec.exe&quot;" Version="2.30.1.3" UninstallParameters="/i {85bb61a2-e0d8-4c3b-83a7-d978dcd4b3d2} REMOVE=DBSERVER /L*V+ &quot;%pFoldrInstallPath%\Foundation\Install\MSI_Uninstall.log&quot; /qn msifeatwise" SupportUninstall="Yes"> </Component>
```

> 

Comment: Need more info. I can't reproduce. `Get-Content .\Desktop\test.xml | Select-String "85bb61a2-e0d8-4c3b-83a7-d978dcd4b3d2"` on a xml file that contains the sample you provided returns the line as it should.

Comment: I'd use a fully-qualified path for the input file, just to be sure the script is reading the same file you are when you do the manual verification.

Answer (score 0):

Try `([String](Get-Content rules.xml)) | Select-String "5351BABA-40C2-477B-8111-DA54A48CD8EB"`.